Apache spark configuration from scratch
I'm trying to configure apache spark from scratch and I installed the following software on Windows 11:

JDK v.22
hadoop 3.3.6 from https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html
hadoop winutils 3.0.0 from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master
spark 3.5.1 with hadoop (I don't find the winutils in it) from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html
scala 2.12.15 from https://www.scala-lang.org/download/

Then, I configured the following Variables with the correct paths:

JAVA_HOME
SCALA_HOME
HADOOP_HOME
SPARK_HOME
PATH

When I try to run the "spark-submit.cmd" command I obtain the error:
"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Failed to find Spark jars directory.
You need to build Spark before running this program."
Can you please help me to fix the error? Thanks in advance
I tried to change the configuration of variables, I also tried to run the scripts located in the SPARK_HOME folder
